# How to show Input text with input radio?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, input

Hello I try to display an input with a radio input unfortunately I do not understand why it does not work .. With this code when I click on the 'No' it shows me the correct input but when I click on the ' Yes' nothing is displayed.
I do not understand why thank you.

```
<div class="login_content_form">
            <%= f.label :post_author_yes, 'Yes' %>
            <%= f.radio_button :author, 'Yes', class: 'edit_input', onclick:'javascript:yesnoCheck();' %>
            <%= f.label :post_author_no, 'No' %>
            <%= f.radio_button :author, 'No', class: 'edit_input', onclick:'javascript:yesnoCheck();' %>
            <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
              <%= f.text_field :author, class: 'edit_input', placeholder: 'Real Author' %>
            </div>
            <div id="ifNo" style="display:none">
            <%= f.text_field :author, class: 'edit_input', value: 'Unknown', :readonly => true %>
          </div>
 </div>
```

And the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('post_author_yes').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'block'
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Html Version :

```
          <div class="login_content_form">
            <label for="post_post_author_yes">Yes</label>
            <input class="edit_input" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" type="radio" value="Yes" name="post[author]" id="post_author_yes" />
            <label for="post_post_author_no">No</label>
            <input class="edit_input" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" type="radio" value="No" name="post[author]" id="post_author_no" />
            <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
              <input class="edit_input" placeholder="Real Author" type="text" name="post[author]" id="post_author" />
            </div>
            <div id="ifNo" style="display:none">
            <input class="edit_input" value="Unknown" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="post[author]" id="post_author" />
          </div>
          </div>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Make sure to use curly braces around your if/else. Don’t omit them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your else statement doesn't have curly braces. Hence the last statement where you turn off the yes block display always executes. Correct this:

```
function yesnoCheck(){
    if(document.getElementById('post_author_yes').checked) 
    {
            document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'block'
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```